# I have to compare user entered id with database id

Tags: java, jdbc, struts2

I have to compare user entered id with database id, but I have not get result and unable to return result properly, and can't do this with below code so please tell me how to do

```
public String execute() throws Exception {
    isValid = doProcessing(getUserid());

    return SUCCESS;
}

public boolean doProcessing(String userid) throws Exception {
    Connection con = null;
   // ResultSet rs = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    boolean status=false;
    try {
        con = ConnectionDB.createConnection();
        pstmt = con.prepareStatement("select userid from attestedform where userid=?");
        pstmt.setString(1, userid);
        ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();


        request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
        session = request.getSession();
        String s = (String) session.getAttribute("UsrBeanLoginId");


        while (rs.next()) {
            id = rs.getString("userid");

            if (s.equalsIgnoreCase(id)) {
                status = true;


            } 
            else
            {

                status=false;
            }

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return status;
   }
   }
```

Comment: What do you expect this code to do, and what doe it do instead? If getting an error, post the stack trace.

Comment: it return false even condition is true.

Comment: Use your debugger, or add traces in the code.

Comment: A System.out.println() will show you why they differ and how...

Comment: Unrelated, but `status = s.equalsIgnoreCase(id)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing different value.

> I have to compare user entered id with database id

Change your code

```java
while (rs.next()) {
    id = rs.getString("userid");

    if (userid.equalsIgnoreCase(id)) {
        status = true;
    } 
    else
    {
        status=false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check your iterator.even iterator found a `id in database`.still it being iterating element.so,make sure, `stop your iterator once`if conditions is true`.

```
  while (rs.next()) {
        id = rs.getString("userid");
        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase(id)) {
            status = true;
            //your COde  Stop you iterator
        } 
        else     status=false;

    }
```